# Erro SQL - erro converter data TYPE VARCHAR para numérico

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, conversão-de-tipo

Boa tarde!
Estou fazendo um SELECT para trazer valores de 2 horários diferentes, porém, ao rodar o script, o mesmo apresenta o erro:

> SQL Error [8114] [S0005]: Error converting data type varchar to
> numeric.

```
SELECT
TOTENERGIA AS 'Totalizador Energia 16h'
, '' AS 'Totalizador Energia 10h'
, TOTVAZAOTM1 AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM1 16h'
, '' AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM1 10h'
, TOTVAZAOTM2 AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM2 16h'
, '' AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM2 10h'
, FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS 'DATA'
, convert(char(19), DIASHORAS, 121) AS 'DATA2'
, convert(char(5), DIASHORAS, 108) AS 'HORAS'
FROM 
TableETE
WHERE
convert(char(8), DIASHORAS, 108) BETWEEN '16:00:00' AND '16:00:04'
UNION SELECT
'' AS 'Totalizador Energia 16h'
, TOTENERGIA AS 'Totalizador Energia 10h'
, '' AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM1 16h'
, TOTVAZAOTM1 AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM1 10h'
, '' AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM2 16h'
, TOTVAZAOTM2 AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM2 10h'
, FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS 'DATA'
, convert(char(19), DIASHORAS, 121) AS 'DATA2'
, convert(char(5), DIASHORAS, 108) AS 'HORAS'
FROM 
TableETE
WHERE
convert(char(8), DIASHORAS, 108) BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '10:00:04'
ORDER BY
HORAS DESC
```

Como posso corrigir esse erro?

Comment: A primeira pergunta é o dado está limpo ? Pelo visto não ? Pode ser limpo ? Em Oracle consegui uma solução em uma base com dados  "sujos" em que não poderia limpar, a conversão é feita por uma function que em bloco protegido tenta converter , tendo erro retorna nulo , não foi a melhor solução mas a possível, o  ideal é sanear a base e ter validações de entrada, por constraints ou triggers.

Comment: `convert(char(5), DIASHORAS, 108)`  isso vai dar mesmo erro, se usou o varlor 108 é sinal que conhece a tabela com os estilos do `convert` e se viu isso deve saber que o 108 formata "hh:mi:ss", ou seja tem o tamanho máximo de 8. Sugiro olhar a tabela, se não tem certeza do tamanho use apenas `NVARCHAR`

Comment: @Motta Pode ser valores sujos, depois irei alterar numa planilha!

Comment: @RicardoPontual Irei verificar um processo sem o CONVERT, é que no caso eu uso o CHAR(5), apenas para trazer a hora e minuto, sem os segundos.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema alterando os valores para VARCHAR.
Ficou assim:

```
SELECT
convert(varchar(MAX), TOTENERGIA) AS 'Totalizador Energia 16h'
, convert(varchar(MAX), '') AS 'Totalizador Energia 10h'
, convert(varchar(MAX), TOTVAZAOTM1) AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM1 16h'
, convert(varchar(MAX), '') AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM1 10h'
, convert(varchar(MAX), TOTVAZAOTM2) AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM2 16h'
, convert(varchar(MAX), '') AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM2 10h'
, FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS 'DATA'
, convert(char(19), DIASHORAS, 121) AS 'DATA2'
, convert(char(5), DIASHORAS, 108) AS 'HORAS'
FROM 
TableETE
WHERE
convert(char(8), DIASHORAS, 108) BETWEEN '16:00:00' AND '16:00:04'
UNION SELECT
convert(varchar(MAX), '') AS 'Totalizador Energia 16h'
, convert(varchar(MAX), TOTENERGIA) AS 'Totalizador Energia 10h'
, convert(varchar(MAX), '') AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM1 16h'
, convert(varchar(MAX), TOTVAZAOTM1) AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM1 10h'
, convert(varchar(MAX), '') AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM2 16h'
, convert(varchar(MAX), TOTVAZAOTM2) AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM2 10h'
, FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS 'DATA'
, convert(char(19), DIASHORAS, 121) AS 'DATA2'
, convert(char(5), DIASHORAS, 108) AS 'HORAS'
FROM 
TableETE
WHERE
convert(char(8), DIASHORAS, 108) BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '10:00:04'
ORDER BY
DATA2 DESC
```